# Click & Drag Mechanism

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I need help with GameMaker Studio 2 v2.3.2.556 project.

My clicking & dragging mechanism has two objects: an object called `obj_iron` that is being dragged, and an object called `obj_cursor` that is invisible and always follows the mouse.  When I use the cursor to drag the iron, nothing happens. How do I make it so I can drag the iron using the cursor?

Code in `obj_cursor` in the Step Event

```
//Making the cursor move toward the mouse
global.picked_up_iron = 0
x = mouse_x
y = mouse_y

//Making the cursor small
image_xscale = 0.1
image_yscale = 0.1

//Checking if the cursor collided with obj_iron
if place_meeting(x,y,obj_iron) 
{
    //Checking if the mouse is held and the cursor is not collided with another obj_iron
    if mouse_check_button(mb_left) and (global.picked_up_iron == 0 or global.picked_up_iron == other)
    {
        //Moving the dragged piece of obj_ironto the obj_cursor's location
        var picked_up_iron = other
        picked_up_iron.x = x - picked_up_iron.sprite_width / 2
        picked_up_iron.y = y - picked_up_iron.sprite_height / 2

        //Telling every the object what the dragged piece of obj_iron is 
        global.picked_up_iron = picked_up_iron
    
    }
} 
else if !mouse_check_button(mb_left)
{
    //Resetting the value of the current piece of obj_iron 
    global.picked_up_iron = 0
}
```

Comment: There can be various things going on when 'nothing happens', so I would recommend setting a breakpoint and debugging your code so you can look into the code step-by-step. My first thought would be that `place_meeting()` does not know which kind of iron is selected, if there are multiple irons in the room. Maybe you can try out `var iron = instance_place(x, y, obj_iron)`, so the `iron` returns the object the cursor is colliding with.

Comment: Thank you!  The code you inserted worked.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you, I'll mark my comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple of the same object in the same room, then `place_meeting()` does not know which kind of object is selected.

Maybe you can try out [Instance_Place](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/objects%20and%20instances/instances/instance%20functions/instance_place.html)

```
var iron = instance_place(x, y, obj_iron);
```

This way, the `iron`  returns the object the cursor is currently colliding with.